# if statement not being recognized [at game() function]

Tags: python-2.7

```
import time
import random
import sys

tries = 1

def start():
    global tries
    tries = 1
    global chest1
    chest1 = random.sample(xrange(1, 20), 1)
    chest1==str
    global chest2
    chest2 = random.sample(xrange(1, 20), 1)
    chest2==str
    global chest3
    chest3 = random.sample(xrange(1, 20), 1)
    chest3==str
    print chest1
    while chest1 == chest2 or chest1 == chest3 or chest2 == chest3:
        start()
    else:
        print"Alright lets begin!"
        game()

def defeat():
    time.sleep(3)
    end = raw_input("Would you like to start again(yes or no)?")
    if end == "yes":
        start()
    if end == "no":
        print"Goodbye!"
        time.sleep(1);
        print"Shutting Down"
        time.sleep(2)
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print"Please input a valid answer"   

def game():
    global chest1
    global chest2
    global chest3
    print chest1, chest2, chest3
    num = input("Choose a chest from 1-20!")
    if num == chest1 or num == chest2 or num == chest3:
        print "Well Done! Get another chest to move on to Sudden Death!"
    else:
        while (tries < 3):
            global tries
            print"Try Again"
            tries = tries + 1
            game()
        else:
            print "You've taken too many tries.. YOU DIE!"
            defeat()
```

When running this code, as I arrive at the if statement:

```
if num == chest1 or num == chest2 or num == chest3:
    print "Well Done! Get another chest to move on to Sudden Death!"
```

and match one of the chests with my input (I know the numbers it chose since I made it print them) it jumps to the else statement and says "Try Again" even though I match the correct input with the chests. I have been at this for hours... Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least a couple of problems:

1. You are assigning a list to `chest1`, `chest2`, `chest3`.
2. The input is a string and you're comparing it to a one-element list with an int.

Try this instead:

```
import time
import random
import sys

tries = 1

def start():
    global tries
    tries = 1
    global chest1
    chest1 = random.randint(1, 20)
    global chest2
    chest2 = random.randint(1, 20)
    global chest3
    chest3 = random.randint(1, 20)
    while chest1 == chest2 or chest1 == chest3 or chest2 == chest3:
        start()
    else:
        print("Alright lets begin!")
        game()

def defeat():
    time.sleep(3)
    end = raw_input("Would you like to start again(yes or no)?")
    if end == "yes":
        start()
    if end == "no":
        print("Goodbye!")
        time.sleep(1);
        print("Shutting Down")
        time.sleep(2)
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Please input a valid answer")

def game():
    global chest1
    global chest2
    global chest3
    print(chest1, chest2, chest3)
    num = int(raw_input("Choose a chest from 1-20!"))
    if num == chest1 or num == chest2 or num == chest3:
        print("Well Done! Get another chest to move on to Sudden Death!")
    else:
        while (tries < 3):
            global tries
            print("Try Again")
            tries = tries + 1
            game()
        else:
            print("You've taken too many tries.. YOU DIE!")
            defeat()
```

Edit: Also using globals is generally frowned upon. I took the liberty of refactoring your code to not use them:

```
import time, random, sys

def start():
    chest1 = random.randint(1, 20)
    chest2 = random.randint(1, 20)
    chest3 = random.randint(1, 20)
    tries = 1
    while chest1 == chest2 or chest1 == chest3 or chest2 == chest3:
        start()
    else:
        print("Alright lets begin!")
        game(chest1,chest2,chest3,tries=tries)
    return tries 

def defeat():
    time.sleep(3)
    end = raw_input("Would you like to start again(yes or no)?")
    if end == "yes":
        tries = start()
    if end == "no":
        print("Goodbye!")
        print("Shutting Down")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Please input a valid answer")

def game(chest1,chest2,chest3,tries=None):
    print(chest1, chest2, chest3)
    num = int(raw_input("Choose a chest from 1-20!"))
    if num == chest1 or num == chest2 or num == chest3:
        print("Well Done! Get another chest to move on to Sudden Death!")
        while (tries < 3):
            tries += 1
            game(chest1,chest2,chest3,tries=tries)
        else:
            print("Moving to Sudden Death!")
            sudden_death(chest1,chest2,chest3,tries=tries)
    else:
        while (tries < 3):
            print("Try Again")
            tries += 1
            game(chest1,chest2,chest3,tries=tries)
        else:
            print("You've taken too many tries.. YOU DIE!")
            defeat()

def sudden_death(chest1,chest2,chest3,tries=None):
    print("Sudden Death not yet implemented; exiting")
    defeat()
```